# Make a scrollable window go to the top of a page if the centered div extents past the top of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a div on my website and it now works but when the window is too small you can't scroll all of the ways to the top of the div. Ideally, if the page's content is larger than the window it si viewed in, it should have a scroll bar that allows scrolling all the way to the top of the aqua box.
I belive that this has to do with the styling in either the body or test classes

the webpage is viewable here:

https://htmltest.duelcraft.pages.dev/

```
<!--(c) 2022 DuelCraft-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DuelCraft</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icon.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body background='images/background.png'>
<div class="body">
  <div class="test">
    <h1>DuelCraft</h1>
    <a href="shop.html">
      <img src="images/shop.png" alt="shop" style="width:100px;height:50px;" class="center">
    </a>
    <p class="main">DuelCraft Minecraft Server</p>
    <h2>How do I join?</h2>
    <p>Connect to play.duelcraft.games</p>
    <div align="center"><iframe src="https://discord.com/widget?id=995858337293926400&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe></div>
    <div class="email-part">
      <p>Email user@example.com for help!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <p class="copyright"> ©2022 DuelCraft </p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  border-style: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: normal 16px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  background-position: top;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #9FE7FF;
  


}

.body{
   
    margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);



}

.email-part {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.copyright{
 color:white;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .test,
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 12vw;
  }
}
```

[image: text]

Comment: _"the webpage is viewable here"_ - good for you, but not that relevant to us - see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) You need to provide a proper [mre] that illustrates your problem, directly within your question.

Comment: there is not enough information on the question and no on will debug your code for you, but it seems to work for me

Comment: @nalm it's only an issue when the window height is smaller than the size of the page, when that happens you can't scroll all of the way to the top of the page.

Comment: Don't use position absolute, unless you know what you are doing. Rather have a look at how CSS works, nothing in the design you showed needs a `position: absolute` anywhere. While you are at it, use standard HTML, `<div align="center">` was valid HTML in 1990, but not today ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ICE_Plane, the trick here is since you are using position absolute ( getting out of the flux )

You need to specify a max height to your `.body` class, like a `max-height: 100vh`.

You could as well add a `overflow-y: auto` to make sure it shows the scrollbar when overflowing

Here is the example you provided working:
[image]

Let me know if that helped, or if you need more info

Comment: that, along with adding `width:100%;` fixed my whole problem, thank you for helping!